# Sometimes clicking on notification sent from firebase console does not open the app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase cloud messaging for push notification and everything works fine. Recently I came across an issue where clicking on the notification sent from Firebase console did not open the app. I was able to reproduce this issue once in One Plus 7 running in Android Pie. I have also noticed that a few devices have taken around 3-10 seconds to open the app when I clicked on the notification(These devices are also running in Android Pie). Is there anyone who has faced a similar issue and can help me understand why this issue happened? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Adding logs that appeared when this issue was reproduced. Here *com.myapp.debug* is the package name of my app.

```
2019-08-16 20:59:40.260 771-812/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2019-08-16 20:59:40.352 3251-3251/? D/NotificationListener: onNotificationRemoved# hash: 174730370 sbn: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.myapp.debug user=UserHandle{0} id=0 tag=campaign_collapse_key_6027743617221419409 key=0|com.myapp.debug|0|campaign_collapse_key_6027743617221419409|10174: Notification(channel=promotions pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0xff0060ec vis=PRIVATE))
2019-08-16 20:59:40.834 1778-1778/? V/StatusBar: mStatusBarWindow: com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.StatusBarWindowView{8aba7fe V.ED..... ........ 0,0-1080,2340} canPanelBeCollapsed(): true
2019-08-16 20:59:40.834 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyFocusableFlag: false, true, false, 81840048
2019-08-16 20:59:40.834 1778-1778/? I/StatusBarWindowManager: applyExpandedFlag expanded:true isCameraLaunched:false
2019-08-16 20:59:40.834 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyNotTouchable: false, isScrimPlaying:false
2019-08-16 20:59:40.847 1778-1778/? I/StatusBar: updateScrimController isInLaunchTransition:false mBouncerShowing:false isKeyguardDone:true mVisible:false isSecure:true isLaunchDial:false
2019-08-16 20:59:40.873 3251-27478/? D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@12df5dc[Launcher]
2019-08-16 20:59:40.967 1778-1778/? D/PreventModeCtrl: onPanelExpandedChange expandtrue mPreventModeActive:false

--------- beginning of system
2019-08-16 20:59:41.082 1212-1276/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.oneplus.security/.network.trafficalarm.TrafficUsageAlarmReceiver
2019-08-16 20:59:40.974 1778-1778/? D/PreventModeCtrl: onPanelExpandedChange expandtrue mPreventModeActive:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.224 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyFocusableFlag: false, true, false, 81840048
2019-08-16 20:59:41.225 1778-1778/? I/StatusBarWindowManager: applyExpandedFlag expanded:true isCameraLaunched:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.225 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyNotTouchable: false, isScrimPlaying:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.325 1778-1778/? D/StatusBar: disable<e i a s b h r c s > disable2<q i n v >
2019-08-16 20:59:41.431 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyFocusableFlag: false, false, false, 81840048
2019-08-16 20:59:41.431 1778-1778/? I/StatusBarWindowManager: applyExpandedFlag expanded:true isCameraLaunched:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.431 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyNotTouchable: false, isScrimPlaying:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.444 1778-1778/? I/StatusBar: updateScrimController isInLaunchTransition:false mBouncerShowing:false isKeyguardDone:true mVisible:false isSecure:true isLaunchDial:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.444 1778-1778/? D/PreventModeCtrl: onPanelExpandedChange expandtrue mPreventModeActive:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.446 1778-1778/? W/NotificationEntryMgr: removeNotification for unknown key: 0|com.myapp.debug|0|campaign_collapse_key_6027743617221419409|10174
2019-08-16 20:59:41.458 1778-1778/? D/AodNotificationIconArea: more than 7 icons
2019-08-16 20:59:41.460 1778-1778/? D/AodNotificationIconArea: more than 7 icons
2019-08-16 20:59:41.480 1778-1955/? D/AppTracker: App Event: portrait_pull
2019-08-16 20:59:41.483 1778-1778/? D/PreventModeCtrl: onPanelExpandedChange expandfalse mPreventModeActive:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.486 1778-1955/? D/AppTracker: App Event: portrait_pull
2019-08-16 20:59:41.492 1778-1955/? D/AppTracker: App Event: portrait_pull
2019-08-16 20:59:41.492 1778-1778/? W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
2019-08-16 20:59:41.493 1778-1778/? W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
2019-08-16 20:59:41.497 1778-1955/? D/AppTracker: App Event: portrait_pull
2019-08-16 20:59:41.503 1778-1778/? D/KeyguardAffordanceView: setCircleRadius: 0.0com.android.systemui.statusbar.KeyguardAffordanceView.setCircleRadiusWithoutAnimation:370 com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.KeyguardAffordanceHelper.updateIcon:450 com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.KeyguardAffordanceHelper.setTranslation:397 com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.KeyguardAffordanceHelper.reset:512 com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.NotificationPanelView.resetViews:677 com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PanelBar.collapsePanel:167 com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.StatusBar.makeExpandedInvisible:3071
2019-08-16 20:59:41.504 1778-1778/? D/PreventModeCtrl: onPanelExpandedChange expandfalse mPreventModeActive:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.504 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyFocusableFlag: false, false, false, 81840048
2019-08-16 20:59:41.504 1778-1778/? I/StatusBarWindowManager: applyExpandedFlag expanded:false isCameraLaunched:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.504 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyNotTouchable: false, isScrimPlaying:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.507 1778-1955/? D/AppTracker: App Event: portrait_pull
2019-08-16 20:59:41.514 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyFocusableFlag: false, false, false, 81840048
2019-08-16 20:59:41.514 1778-1778/? I/StatusBarWindowManager: applyExpandedFlag expanded:false isCameraLaunched:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.514 1778-1778/? D/StatusBarWindowManager: applyNotTouchable: false, isScrimPlaying:false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.514 1778-1778/? D/StatusBar: disable<e i a s b h r c s > disable2<q i n v >
2019-08-16 20:59:41.515 1778-1778/? D/AbstractTracker: Event success
2019-08-16 20:59:41.515 1778-1778/? D/AbstractTracker: Event success
2019-08-16 20:59:41.515 1778-1778/? D/QSPanel: setListening: true->false
2019-08-16 20:59:41.516 1778-1778/? D/AbstractTracker: Event success
2019-08-16 20:59:41.546 1778-1778/? I/chatty: uid=10022(com.android.systemui) identical 1 line
2019-08-16 20:59:41.550 1778-1778/? D/AbstractTracker: Event success
2019-08-16 20:59:42.449 799-1261/? I/SurfaceFlinger: fusionlight RGB time gap 21 ms
2019-08-16 20:59:42.450 1212-1462/? D/SensorService: FusionLight, InLux = 93.709724, outLux = 69.133057
2019-08-16 20:59:44.698 1212-1276/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.oneplus.security/.network.trafficalarm.TrafficUsageAlarmReceiver
```

Comment: We are also facing similar issue. No info to debug this.